# Computer Architecture: Hit ratio with address

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

There is a problem that as much as I am trying to understand it, I fail. There are theoretically three cache manufacturers that each make 16 byte cache. The first has 16 blocks, 8 blocks the second, and 4 blocks the last. Then we are provided with 12 memory addresses, and we are asked the hit ratio of each cache. How does this work?

Comment: Please spend more effort typing your question.

Comment: I believe there is more information in the question than what you have typed here. Anyway, first calculate how many bits are needed to TAG, Index of each cache. Then look at the memory address sequence you have been given and "play" the sequence marking hits and misses.

Comment: Maybe you are asked inequalities, X≤Y≤Z. Assuming random accesses, which one will get the best hit rate, which one is the worst ? (Note that the best configuration is also the one that needs the most hardware)